# pydantic root_validator: mypy strict type checking

Tags: python, validation, mypy, python-typing, pydantic

I'm looking for the "proper" way to have strict type checking within a pydantic `root_validator` decorated method.

Take the example below: in the `validate_model` method, I want to be able to use mypy strict type-checking. As both `first_name` and `age` have been validated and type-checked by the time this method is called, we can assume that `values['first_name']` and `values['age']` are of type 'str' and 'int' respectively.

You can see the `# type:ignore` "hack" that I've used to allow type hinting and to stop mypy complaining, but it's pretty ugly, and could create bugs if I change any of the variable types. Ideally, a `root_validator` decorated method would have the `values` argument be of same type as the class `SimpleModel` itself, or there should be a simple way to convert `SimpleModel` into a `TypedDict`, so we can use this in the `validate_model` signature, for example:
`def validate_model(cls, values: SimpleModelTypedDict) -> SimpleModelTypedDict`

Anyway, if there is anyone out there that has run into a similar issue, please, let me know how you have tackled it.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

class SimpleModel(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    age: int

@root_validator(skip_on_failure=True)
def validate_model(cls, values: dict) -> dict:
    """checks there are no Bobs under 60 (sorry Bob!)"""
    first_name: str = values.get("first_name")  # type:ignore
    age: int = values.get("age")  # type:ignore
    if first_name.lower() == "bob" and age < 60:
        raise ValueError("No Bobs under 60")

    return values
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct type hints for `first_name` and `age` should be `Optional[str]` and `Optional[int]`, respectively. The `.get()` method of a `dict` can return `None` and this `values` dict of a validator will if there is no field that corresponds to the provided name or it is invalid: a validation failed previously for that field. You use `skip_on_failure=True` and I believe it should cover the case of a previously failed validation, but the return value of `.get()` can still be `None` if for some reason you try to get a field that does not exist.

Using that type hint you should validate if the `first_name` and `age` variables are `None` before trying to do any additional validations.

Full example:

```python
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


class SimpleModel(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    age: int


@root_validator(skip_on_failure=True)
def validate_model(cls, values: dict) -> dict:
    """checks there are no Bobs under 60 (sorry Bob!)"""
    first_name: Optional[str] = values.get("first_name")
    age: Optional[int] = values.get("age")
    if first_name is not None and age is not None and first_name.lower(
    ) == "bob" and age < 60:
        raise ValueError("No Bobs under 60")

    return values
```

Comment: The return type of `values.get("first_name")` is `Any`. The return type of `values.get("first_name", None)` would be `Optional[Any]`. Unfortunately, either way, the typing would not include `str`.

Comment: @Hampycalc, did you try the example? And the return type of `values.get("first_name")` according to `reveal_type(values.get("first_name"))` is: `Revealed type is "Union[Any, None]"` which is equivalent to `Optional[Any]`. Check these sections in the mypy documentation: [Displaying the type of an expression](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html?highlight=reveal_type#displaying-the-type-of-an-expression) and [Explicit types for variables](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_inference_and_annotations.html#explicit-types-for-variables).

Comment: Sure, the question here is really about getting the type of `first_name` in the `root_validator` decorated class method...